# Is there a function $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ with inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{g^{-1}(x)}{h^{-1}(x)}$?

Tags: functions

I can't seem to find any function that satisfy these criteria. Let's say $f$ is a function (be in the reals or elsewhere) that's a quotient of two other functions $g$ and $h$ means $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, and its inverse $f^{-1}$ is the quotient of the respective inverse functions $g^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}$ means $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{g^{-1}(x)}{h^{-1}(x)}.$ If such functions exists, is there a name for this property?

Comment: 1. You should use MathJax to write math in your questions. 2. Are you satisfied with the identity function?

Comment: Thank you for answering, yea the identity function is one of them, but are there any more you can think of?

Comment: You should revise your question accordingly.

Comment: How is the identity function a solution? What are $g$ and $h$?

Comment: Are we allowing the solution where $h(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: $h(x)=1$ is not invertible. People seem to be confusing the identity function with the constant $1$ function, or maybe confusing function inverses with multiplicative inverses.

Comment: No.  There is no name for that property.  I don't think anyone considered it significant.  It'd be interesting to try to find some.  I'm sure there are some.  We could try $g(x)=x^r; h(x)=x^s; f(x)=x^{r-s}; g^{-1}=x^{\frac 1r},h^{-1}=x^{\frac 1s}; f^{-1}= x^{\frac 1{r-s}}$ and try to solve for $\frac 1{r-s}= \frac 1r -\frac 1s$ (i.e. $\frac 1{r-s}=\frac{s-r}{rs}; rs =-(r-s)^2; r^2 + 3rs +s^2 = 0$ and so on....)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, $f(x)=e^{\frac{2}{\log x}}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}}{e^{\frac{-1}{\log x}}}$ for $x\ne 0, 1$. I'm not aware of a name for this property.

Answer (score 3):

An amusing example is $f(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}, g(x) = -x, h(x) = 1-x$, for $x \ne 1$.  Here each of $f$, $g$ and $h$ is its own functional inverse, so $f^{-1} = g^{-1}/h^{-1}$ because $f = g/h$.